# Question on circular random walk

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, markov-process, random-walk

A truck transports goods among $10$ points located on a circular route. These goods are carried only from one point to the next with probability $p$, or to the preceding point with probability $q=1-p$.

1. Write the transition probability matrix.
2. Find the limiting stationary distribution.
3. Write your conclusions about this question.

Comment: Hi, welcome to MSE. It is important to show your attempt and ask specific questions.

Comment: What are your thoughts on the problem? What have you tried? Have you been able to find the matrix in question? Do you understand all the terminology being used here?

Comment: For 2: the fact that the Markov chain is transitive (and irreducible) tells us that the stationary distribution must be uniform.

Comment: yes, i tried and i found the matrix. and i understand all the terminology being used here.but i was looking for a simple idea to find the limiting and i have a sense that the $pi=1/10

Comment: i think that the limiting stationary distribution will be 1/10 but i want to prove that.

Comment: @AhmadZaben Great. It would be great if you could add that information to your post, and include context like this in future questions.  See [this post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959/81360) for more information.

Comment: oh thanks, i will try to take ur advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The transition matrix is the [circulant matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circulant_matrix#Other_properties) $M = q \cdot P + p \cdot P^T$, where $P$ is the permutation matrix in the link. Computing the stationary distribution can be done by computing the solution to the system $(M - I)x = 0$.

However, rather than solving this system of equations, we can more easily prove that your guess of the stationary distribution $\pi = (1/10,\dots,1/10)$ is correct by verifying that $\pi M = M$.  To see that this holds, note that $\pi = \frac 1{10} (1,\dots,1)$, and that the entries of $(1,\dots,1)M$ are the column-sums of $M$. The only non-zero entries of a given column of $M$ are $p$ and $q$, which means that every entry of $(1,\dots,1)M$ will be $p+q = 1$, which means that we have
$$
(1,\dots,1)M = (1,\dots,1)M \implies \pi M = \pi.
$$
So, $\pi$ is indeed the stationary distribution.